# How to force weights of neural net away from zero?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, loss-functions

I am trying to construct a deep hidden physics model to learn the boundary layer equations. Simply put, I want to use a neural net to combine some input terms such that the boundary layer equations are recovered. Because I don't want to "cheat" my way to the answer, by for example setting the loss function equal to the the result of the neural net minus the r.h.s. of the BL-equations, I seem to be forced to set the loss equal to the output of the neural net. I do, indeed, want the network to learn how to combine all terms such that they yield zero, but not by simply setting all weights to zero. So, what I think I need is a kind of reversed-regularization term, which forces the weights at least a little away from zero.

Is there a smart way of doing this? I could for example subtract the norm of the weights from some set non-zero value, but that seems like a less than optimal solution. Or does this approach maybe not make sense anyway?

Thank you in advance for any help.

**tldr: I want a network that outputs zero, but using non-zero weights. How to do this?**

Comment: You’re trying to perform a constrained optimization problem. A neural network isn’t the natural tool for this, and you’ll be fighting an uphill battle.